# How to declare S3 method to default to loaded environment?

Tags: r, namespaces, r-s3

In a package, I would like to call an S3 method "compact" for object `foobar`.

There would therefore be a `compact.foobar` function in my package, along with the `compact` function itself:

```
compact = function(x, ...){
    UseMethod("compact", x)
}
```

However, this latter would be conflicting with `purrr::compact`.

I could default the method to use `purrr` (`compact.default = purrr::compact`, or maybe 
`compact.list = purrr::compact`), but that would make little sense if the user does not have `purrr` loaded.

How can I default my method to the loaded version of `compact`, in the user environment? (so that it uses `purrr::compact`, any other declared `compact` function, or fails of missing function)

Comment: What about hypothetical package ‘xyz’ that also declares `compact`? (The answer to this matters for a potential solution.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's what I meant with "in the user environment". If the user has loaded `purrr`, `xyz`, both, or anything else, if the object is not of class `foobar`, my method should use whatever `compact` function it is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately S3 does not deal with this situation well. You have to search for suitable functions manually. The following works, more or less:

```
get_defined_function = function (name) {
    matches = getAnywhere(name)
    # Filter out invisible objects and duplicates
    objs = matches$objs[matches$visible & ! matches$dups]
    # Filter out non-function objects
    funs = objs[vapply(objs, is.function, logical(1L))]
    # Filter out function defined in own package.
    envs = lapply(funs, environment)
    funs = funs[! vapply(envs, identical, logical(1L), topenv())]
    funs[1L][[1L]] # Return `NULL` if no function exists.
}
```

```
compact.default = function (...) {
    # Maybe add error handling for functions not found.
    get_defined_function('compact')(...)
}
```

This uses `getAnywhere` to find all objects named `compact` that R knows about. It then filters out those that are not visible because they’re not inside attached packages, and those that are duplicate (this is probably redundant, but we do it anyway).

Next, it filters out anything that’s not a function. And finally it filters out the `compact` S3 generic that our own package defines. To do this, it compares each function’s environment to the package environment (given by `topenv()`).

This should work, but it has no rule for which function to prefer if there are multiple functions with the same name defined in different locations (it just picks an arbitrary one first), and it also doesn’t check whether the function signature matches (doing this is hard in R, since function calling and parameter matching is very flexible).

Comment: Awesome! I had to change the last line to `unlist(funs[[1L]])` for it to work, but after a few tests, it seems to be perfect. This should definitely be in some util package!

Comment: @DanChaltiel Hmm no, that change should *not* work: `funs[[1L]]` is already a single element, no need for `unlist`, and this will fail if the list is empty. Whereas my code will return `NULL`. The last line is in effect equivalent to `if (length(funs) > 0L) funs[[1L]] else NULL`.

Comment: This is strange, while what you say makes perfect sense, on my computer it fails with `[1L]` and runs with `[[1L]]`. Somehow, the `unlist` call didn't have any effect...

Comment: With `browser()`, I have `identical(funs[1L],unlist(funs[1L]))==TRUE`. How uncanny! But indeed, it fails if there is no `compact` function loaded.

Comment: @DanChaltiel Thanks for your debugging work, I’ve had another look and was able to reproduce it, no idea how my code ever worked in the first place. The fix should now work, although I’m slightly concerned that the code is a bit too obscure, and that using an explicit `if` might be better after all …

Comment: Actually, I stuck with the function returning a list, and used `fn=get_defined_function('compact'); fn[[1L]](...)` in `compact.default`. This way I can perform tests on the function and throw an error is `fn` is null.